# grep string from contents of file command then delete file

Tags: shell, files, grep, pipe, rm

I have a large batch of .docx files where a certain number of them are junk.  I know how to identify these files from the file command, as they contain the phrase "Number of Words: 161" from the output of file cmd.  I need to delete these files.  I have the following so far,

```
file * | grep "Number of Words: 161"
```

which gives an output similar to

```
19028409: CDF V2 Document, Little Endian, Os: Windows, Version 5.1, Code page: 1252, Author: author, Template: Normal, Last Saved By:  , Revision Number: 2, Name of Creating Application: Microsoft Office Word, Last Printed: Mon Dec 13 13:21:00 2010, Create Time/Date: Wed Dec 12 22:39:00 2012, Last Saved Time/Date: Wed Dec 12 22:38:00 2012, Number of Pages: 1, Number of Words: 161, Number of Characters: 923, Security: 0
```

where the filename is 19028409

How can I delete all instances of these files?  I should also add that I am running this from the MAC OS X terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
for f in ./*docx; do file "$f" | grep -q "Number of Words: 161" && rm "$f"; done
```

This will loop through all `.docx` files in the current directory and delete them if the exit code of `grep` is 0. `grep` will return 0 if the current file matches the string you searched for. The `-q` is just to suppress output.

To make sure this works as expected, run it with `printf`first:

```
for f in ./*docx; do 
 file "$f" | grep -q "Number of Words: 161" && 
   printf "%s\n" "rm $f"
done
```

Comment: This worked for me thanks, I also like that you added the sanity check with printf :).  I made one small alteration since my files don't actually end with docx, so I just used *

Comment: @user251482 fair enough, I just used `*docx` to skip directories.

Answer (score 0):

So long as no filenames have colons in them:

```
IFS="\n" for f in $(file * | grep "Number of Words: 161" | sed 's/:.*$//'); do
 rm "$file"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, it's giving me "syntax error near unexpected token 'do'"

Comment: I rolled back your edit because there _is_ a need to use `file`. The string `Number of Words: 161` is in the output of `file` ot in the `.docx` document itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't find the answer, how about:

```
for i in `file *|grep "Number of Words"|awk -F ":" '{print $1}'`
do
rm $i
done
```

Comment: Note, put back quotes from the word file to the end of the line...